# Docker containers unable to apt-get update or Yum-update

Tags: docker, jenkins, yum, apt-get

I have docker installed on jenkins server. Jenkin server is able to connect to internet successfully and resolv.conf is the same, both in Host and in the containers thar are created. I have many images already downloaded on jenkins server (centos, ubuntu) that are used for many different jobs.
All this jenkins jobs which were made for creating containers, were working ok.
Now suddenly some jobs stopped working with following error.

```
Step 3/21 : RUN yum update -y && yum install epel-release  initscripts policycoreutils selinux-policy-targeted -y --skip-broken
 ---> Running in 5e61a8b671ad
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Determining fastest mirrors
[91m

 One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=<repoid> ...

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=<repoid>

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true

Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base/7/x86_64
[0mCould not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=container error was
14: HTTP Error 403 - Forbidden
The command '/bin/sh -c yum update -y && yum install epel-release  initscripts policycoreutils selinux-policy-targeted -y --skip-broken' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

So I tried accessing jenkis server directly and creating a new and different  container manually from other image,  which was ubuntu instead of centos (the one of the job that failed), and also got following:

```
sudo docker run -ti --name testt cont.azurecr.io/app-be-dev:nginx bash
root@5959696258a0:/# apt-get update
Ign:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Ign:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release
Ign:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates Release
Ign:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
Ign:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
Ign:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
Ign:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
Ign:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
Ign:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
Ign:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:9 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
Ign:10 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates Release
Ign:11 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
Ign:12 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:11 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
Ign:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
Ign:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
Ign:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
Ign:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:12 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:11 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
Ign:12 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:11 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
Ign:12 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
Ign:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
Ign:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
Ign:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
Ign:11 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
Ign:12 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:11 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
Err:12 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
  403  Forbidden [IP: 128.101.240.215 80]
Ign:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
Ign:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
Ign:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
Err:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
  403  Forbidden [IP: 128.31.0.62 80]
Ign:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
Ign:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
Err:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
  403  Forbidden [IP: 128.31.0.62 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 128.31.0.62 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 128.31.0.62 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/stretch/updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 128.101.240.215 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
root@5959696258a0:/# apt-get update
Ign:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
Ign:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates Release
Ign:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
Ign:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Ign:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease
Ign:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release
Ign:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates Release
Ign:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
Ign:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
Ign:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
Ign:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
Ign:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
Ign:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
Err:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
  **403  Forbidden [IP: 128.31.0.63 80]**
Ign:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
Err:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
  403  Forbidden [IP: 130.89.148.14 80]
Ign:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
Ign:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
Err:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
  403  Forbidden [IP: 130.89.148.14 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/stretch/updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 128.31.0.63 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 130.89.148.14 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 130.89.148.14 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

As you see also 403 error from different image and manually instead of from job. Only thing that was donde on jenkins server, was a reboot some days ago due some plug -in actualization.
I repeat, resolv.conf in container is the same as the host (jenkins), I also tried docker run -dns 8.8.8.8 which configured google DNS in container, but also got same problem.

What can be causing this 403 error?. I also tried an `apt-get update` from jenkins itself and the update was made successully. Is like on host everything ok but on containers no. could it be that the network bridge is not working?
thank you

UPDATE1

```
root@4926b1da2bd1:/# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
192.168.1.1     4926b1da2bd1
```

UPDATE 2 Solved it restarting docker networking bridge and flushing iptables:

```
pkill docker
iptables -t nat -F
ifconfig docker0 down
brctl delbr docker0
docker -d
```

Comment: what repo domain names do you have in the etc hosts file you've been grooming?

Comment: this is what I have on etc/hosts in container. (updated question)

Comment: okay, I thought you were doing some management there but that all looks pretty stock.

Comment: and on jenkins host I have the same exept last line which has:

67.219.148.138 mirrorlist.centos.org    

but this shouldn´t be the issue I guess since for debian also have same problem with apt-get

Comment: I'm curious what motivated the addition of that centos address to your /etc/hosts, because it seems that whatever the motivating factor was, it would also affect your docker containers on that host

Comment: don´t know...was that way always I guess...or not. Do you suggest removing that from jenkins host? or to adding it to the hosts file  in the container?....hmm

Comment: Just `iptables -t nat -F` & restarting docker solves my problem.